# Modify Font Family on User Input with Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-input, addeventlistener, event-listener, font-family

I want my text area to render another font (besides monospace) while the user types. My goal was to use Javascript to achieve this.

Below is a script for changing the user input to uppercase (in real time,) as typed. However, I have not been able to find a solution to my problem, by using the below script as a template.

```
    <div id="thoughts-textarea">
      <label for="thoughts">Additional thoughts?</label><br>
      <textarea name="thoughts" id="thoughts" cols="30" rows="5" 
      placeholder="Enter any comments here..."></textarea>
    </div>
```

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let thoughts = document.getElementById("thoughts");
  thoughts.addEventListener('input', fontFam);
});

function fontFam(ev){
  let num = ev.charCode;
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(num);
  console.log(ev.type, num, letter, ev.target.value);
  ev.target.value = ev.target.value.toUpperCase();
}
</script>
```

e.g. I have tried splicing in...

```
function fontFam(ev){
  let num = ev.charCode;
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(num);
  console.log(ev.type, num, letter, ev.target.style);
  ev.target.style = ev.target.style.fontFamily = "Nunito, sans-serif";
}

function fontFam(ev){
  let num = ev.charCode;
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(num);
  console.log(ev.type, num, letter, ev.target.style);
  ev.target.style = ev.target.style.font = "Nunito, sans-serif";
}

function fontFam(ev){
  let num = ev.charCode;
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(num);
  console.log(ev.type, num, letter, ev.target.value.style);
  ev.target.value.style = ev.target.value.style.font = "Nunito, sans-serif";
}
```

...and multiple other variations, and still can't find a working solution.

Thanks for your time and effort,

Malik

p.s. This is my second post. Apologies if I've yet to learn proper procedure (for javascript & SO posts.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close, see my updated snippet below:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  let thoughts = document.getElementById("thoughts");
  thoughts.addEventListener('input', fontFam);
});

function fontFam(ev){
  let num = ev.charCode;
  let letter = String.fromCharCode(num);
  console.log(ev.type, num, letter, ev.target.value);
  ev.target.style.fontFamily = "Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif";
}
```

```html
<div id="thoughts-textarea">
  <label for="thoughts">Additional thoughts?</label><br>
  <textarea name="thoughts" id="thoughts" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Enter any comments here..."></textarea>
</div>
```

I used the `impact` font-family in my example but with your code I would simply adjust:

`ev.target.value.style = ev.target.value.style.font = "Nunito, sans-serif";`

To:

`ev.target.value.style.font = "Nunito, sans-serif";`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a FontFace and apply FontFamily to body
you also need to make a function that gets executed whenever user clicks on a button to change font. eg. `changeFont(fontName)`

```js
async function changeFont(fontName, fontUrl, options={}) {
    const ff = new FontFace(fontName, `url(${fontUrl})`, options);
    try {
     const loadedFont = await ff.load()
     document.fonts.add(loadedFont)
     document.body.style.fontFamily = fontName
    } catch (err) {
     console.error(err)
    }
}
```

Then you can use the function as eg.

```js
await changeFont('Junction Regular', 'fonts/junction-regular.woff', { style:'normal', weight: 700' })
```